# Interpretation of owning ethereum

Tags: ether

Owning ethereum can be interpreted as owning the ledger record entry in the  blockchain and the entry is signed by my private key. Is this correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, "Ethereum" is the name of the blockchain, and "Ether" is the name of its native currency, used to pay for gas for transactions.

You can be said to "own" any ether represented by a non-zero balance of an address for which you know the private key (or a contract address which *itself* has a similarly defined access to funds, with which your address is authorized to interact).

Knowing the private key makes you capable of signing transactions/messages from this address, thereby proving that you know the private key, and enabling you to spend its funds.

Of course, if I steal your private key, I don't "own" your tokens in a legal sense - but in a technical sense, you bet I do!

Answer (score 0):

We could say that you truly own a private key for a particular address.

With that private key, you are allowed to sign transactions for that address (such as send Ether).

The Ethereum blockchain is simply a record/ledger/database. The database says that each address as a specific balance of Ether. The address that you currently control with the private key that you own has a balance > 0 of Ether. Your private key allows you to reduce that balance by increasing the balance of another address (what we commonly call "sending" ether).